# Unable to connect hive through JDBC java

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, kerberos

I am trying to connect hive through java(eclipse). Hive is working on the linux server, where I have installed it.

I have imported all the jar files.

I am using this code

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
try {
Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}

final String keyPath = "Here is the keypath";
final String user = "myuser/FQDN@REALM.COM";
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "PATH:/krb5.conf");
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
UserGroupInformation ugi;
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(user, keyPath);
UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(ugi);
System.out.println("TRYING TO CONNECT");
Connection cnct = null;
cnct = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:hive2://FQDN:10000/default;principal=ADDED PRINCIPAL HERE",
                    "user", "pass");
            System.out.println("Connected");
        cnct.close();
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not open connection to jdbc:hive2://FQDN:10000/default;principal=PRINCIPAL HERE: Peer indicated failure: GSS initiate failed
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:146)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:123)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at TestHiveJdbc.main(TestHiveJdbc.java:56)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Peer indicated failure: GSS initiate failed
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:190)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:258)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:144)
    ... 5 more
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: #1 Just to confirm -- the `principal=...` that you use in Hive JDBC URL is the **HiveServer2 service principal** right? #2 -- you dont need a `UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(ugi);`.

Comment: @mazaneicha I believe it is. Can you please tell how to check the server principal on linux server?

Comment: @mazaneicha I added the server principal using ./kadmin.local: addprinc myuser/FQDN@REALM.COM

Comment: The principal you have added for your user id is irrelevant. In connection URL, `principal=...` must be the HiveServer2 service principal. It can be found in your `hive-site.xml`, just look for `hive.server2.authentication.kerberos.principal` and copy it from there.

Comment: @mazaneicha I have added that principal only. But Still, the error is the same.